# Add Links of other windows phone applications into my windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone application where I decide to add links to all my other published windows phone apps . I tried it by giving direct link to like windowsphone.com/appid but its not working. 
I wasted many hours searching it but couldn't find any answer , It must be a very simple solution but unfortunately I am not getting it.

Please help me for it.

Thanks

Zauk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows Phone 8, you've an API which gives all the apps published by you. The API can be used as:

```
IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
```

You can find more information about this API here: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: There's also the [`MarketplaceDetailTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017(v=vs.105).aspx)?